# How would I put this code into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to put this into a function newton(x) that allows users to enter there value for x.

```
from math import *
x=20
for iteration in range(1, 1001):

        xnew = x - (((3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5)))*(1-exp(-.12*x))))-1)/(.12*(3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5))))*(1-exp(-.12*x)*(-.12*x))) # the Newton-Raphson's formula
        print("Error",x-xnew," Xn:   ", xnew)
        if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
            break  

        x = xnew  
print('The root : %0.5f' % xnew)
print('The number of iterations : %d' % iteration)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a function that returns a 2-tuple:

```
from math import *

def newton(x):
    xnew = iteration = None
    for iteration in range(1, 1001):
            xnew = x - (((3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5)))*(1-exp(-.12*x))))-1)/(.12*(3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5))))*(1-exp(-.12*x)*(-.12*x))) # the Newton-Raphson's formula
            print("Error",x-xnew," Xn:   ", xnew)
            if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
                break  
            x = xnew
    return xnew, iteration

xnew, iteration = newton(20)
print('The root : %0.5f' % xnew)
print('The number of iterations : %d' % iteration)
```